# mouseover action run just once (how to)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to load data(via ajax)  in a tooltip when the mouse is over a specific area. The problem is that the ajax call is made as long as my mouse is on that area. Is there any way, that I could make onmouseover (ajax call) efect happen just once? Here is the code:

```
$.post('calendar/event-details', {'eventId' :event.id},
            function (data){
                this.top = (ui.clientY + 15); this.left = (ui.clientX - 230);
                $('body').append( '<div id="vtip">' + data + '</div>' );
                $('div#vtip').css("top", this.top+"px").css("left", this.left+"px").fadeIn("slow");
                $('div#vtip').css("position","absolute");
                $('div#vtip').css("z-index", "+99");
            })
```

Comment: Where is your HTML, and where is your code which binds the mouseover event?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With [`.one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/):

```
$('element').one('mouseover', function() { /* ajax */ });
```

`.one` will detach the handler as soon as it is executed. As a result, it won't execute any more times.

Answer (score 9):

You may want to hook your function to the `onMouseEnter` event instead of the `onMouseOver` event, along with a function hooked to the `onMouseLeave` event that hides the tooltip:

```
$('element').mouseenter(function() {
    /* Make request, show tooltip */
});
$('element').mouseleave(function() {
    /* Hide tooltip */
});
```

*Note that the pure JS versions of these events are IE only, jQuery simulates the behaviour for other browsers*

Comment: helped me a lot! Thx.

Answer (score 7):

Use modern JS!

```
node.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    // Load data here
}, {once : true});
```

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/addeventlistener-once), [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=once-event-listener)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a long time since this has been a topic but for anyone looking for an easy alternative:

Set a static variable and check the last id used.
If the last id is the current id, do nothing; quick example below

```
var LastId = null;

function Hover(Id){
    if(Id!= LastId){
        LastId = Id;
        $(Id).hide('fast');
    }else{
      //Do nothing; this will keep the function from recalling 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you need to use `onmouseenter` instead of `onmouseover`
please read the docs [here](http://%20%5Bw3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseenter.asp%5D%5B1%5D)